# Microsoft SQL Server compatibility issue (C# Application)

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am developing a C# application on Windows 10, under Visual Studio 2015.
I can see that I have installed on that PC Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition, 2012 Native Client, 2014 Express LocalDB, 2016 Local DB and other stuff like this.
I did not voluntarily installed any of this, they must have been with MVS 2015 or with the Windows.

The app that I made throws an exception on a Windows 7 PC with Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 and all the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 specific stuff (including Express LocalDB).

If I run sqllocaldb i command on Win10 PC I have only mssqllocaldb connection with 13.0.1601.5 version number.
On Win7 PC I have the same status except that the version is 12.0.2000.8.

When I run my application I get
`This server supports version 782 and earlier, your version is 852.`

What can I do so that I can run the app in both computers since I have SQL Server 2014 on both of them fully installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431043/cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-852-this-server-supports-version-782-and ?

Comment: Thank you for the link, but there is no solution either. If you check the initiator comments you will see that those answers did not helped him to solve his problem. Neither helped me. :( How could I force the project to use SQL 2014 without prompting me for upgrade?