# Getting Error in opening .mdf Database in asp.net application

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error while accessing database :

> The database 'E:\WORKSPACE\xxx\xxx\APP_DATA\xxxxxxxxxx.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.Could not open new database.

Actually, i have copied the complete solution from one system to other and trying to run it but getting the above error. All DLL and all References are added correctly.
I also installed SQL Server 2017 Express Edition on my system still setting the error.

Please guide me to the solution for this.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: I think its related to SQL Server not related to asp.net or C#

Comment: You need a more recent version of SQL Server.  The file format for the database moves forward each release

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46431772/3194005

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot be opened because it is version 852. this server supports version 782 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431043/cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-852-this-server-supports-version-782-and)