# Can’t open SQL .MDF file because it’s version 852

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, localdb

I’ve created a C# application and have published it. I tested the published application on my own computer and everything was working properly. When I installed the app on my client’s computer that has the same SQL Server version installed as mine, when I want to open the app, I get this error:

> Can’t use or open database because it’s version 852 
>   and this machine supports 706 or earlier.

I’ve installed SSMS, SQL Server Express, a higher version (2017) of SQL Server, but none of the above helped. I’m frustrated, what can I do?

My App.Config file is like this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLOCALDB;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\SLApp.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
```

Everything works fine on my computer with the config mentioned above. Now what can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431043/cannot-be-opened-because-it-is-version-852-this-server-supports-version-782-and#46431772

Comment: Yeah, I’ve seen that but that didn’t help either.

Comment: @Jacob This error is when multiple instances exists at the same time on the same computer.

Comment: @Franck You mean server instances? How can I remove other instances on the computer? If that didn’t help, what am I supposed to do then?

Comment: @Jacob you can't always removed them. Sometime other software has them embedded so you have to deal with and when attaching your database to the instance you need to find all engine installed and add the to the correct version you want it to run with.

Comment: @Franck There are no attachments here. I only have the .MDF file on my client’s PC and that’s all. I don’t want to attach the database to SSMS.

Comment: Did you install "SQL Server Express LocalDB"? Upgrading the standard Sql Server Express will not help you ... your App.config shows you are using LocalDb ...